# (Iterative?) Solutions to a certain quadratic program with non-convex constraints

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, quadratic-programming, non-convex-optimization

Let $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$, $\tau\in\mathbb{R}$ and $X\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, with $\tau>0$

I would like to efficiently solve the following problem:

---

#### Problem 1

Choose $\alpha,z\in\mathbb{R}^m,\beta\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to minimize:
$$(y-\alpha)^\top (y-\alpha) + \tau \beta^\top \beta$$
subject to the constraints that:
$$z=X\beta$$
$$\beta^\top 1_n = 1$$
$$\beta\ge 0$$
$$\forall i,j\in\{1,\dots,m\}, z_i\le z_j \rightarrow \alpha_i \le \alpha_j$$

---

(Here $1_n\in\mathbb{R}^n$ is a vector of ones.)

The final constraint is equivalent to:

$$\forall i,j\in\{1,\dots,m\}, (z_j-z_i,\alpha_j-\alpha_i)\in\left\{(c,d)\in\mathbb{R}^2\middle|c\le 0 \vee d\ge 0\right\},$$

which is clearly non-convex. While the problem can be given a mixed integer quadratic programming formulation, this is unlikely to be computationally feasible.

However, if we knew $z=\hat z$, Problem 1 reduces to:

---

#### Problem 2

Choose $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^m$ to minimize:
$$(y-\alpha)^\top (y-\alpha)$$
subject to the constraints that:
$$\forall i,j\in\{1,\dots,m\}, \hat z_i\le \hat z_j \rightarrow \alpha_i \le \alpha_j$$

---

This is the isotonic regression problem, and may be solved very efficiently by the pooled adjacent violators algorithm.

Likewise, if we knew $\alpha=\hat\alpha$, then Problem 1 reduces to:

---

#### Problem 3

Choose $z\in\mathbb{R}^m,\beta\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to minimize:
$$\beta^\top \beta$$
subject to the constraints that:
$$z=X\beta$$
$$\beta^\top 1_n = 1$$
$$\beta\ge 0$$
$$\forall i,j\in\{1,\dots,m\}, \hat\alpha_i > \hat\alpha_j \rightarrow z_i > z_j$$

---

This is a simple quadratic programming problem (at least once the strict inequality on $z$ is replaced by a weak one with a small margin).

#### Question

My question is whether Problem 2 or Problem 3 can be exploited to give a computationally feasible (iterative?) algorithm for Problem 1. I would of course also be interested in any other approach to efficiently solving Problem 1.

Note that the naïve algorithm of alternating between solving Problem 2 and solving Problem 3 cannot possibly converge to a solution of Problem 1, as neither Problem 2 nor 3 depend on $\tau$.

Comment: http://or.stackexchange.com

Comment: Good suggestion! Now reposted here: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/4498/iterative-solutions-to-a-certain-quadratic-program-with-non-convex-constraint